# Upgrading Angular 2 version

Tags: angular

I want to know if upgrading my angular version from 2.1 to the latest version can cause some problems in my application? I am not really sure but i want to update my version in order to use some plugins. Any advice please?

Comment: Read the changelog. Then try doing it. Than execute your tests.

Comment: Cannot guarantee as we don't know what parts of the framework you are using. But angular is using Semantic versioning which is usefully for answering your question.  http://semver.org/

Comment: @StevenJohnston, Few days back, i ran the command npm update and my package.json file updated. My application failed to load the links and bootstrap files links in my index.html.

Comment: It's stable but there are  a few things that no longer silently fail and instead throw errors

Comment: This blog may be usefull http://laxmanchavda.blogspot.com/2021/05/upgrade-angular-version-to-latest.html